# rename a childnode in a xml document

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

i got a problem with a parser.

i want to parse an xml structured like this:

```
<item>
...
   <notes>
        <item>
        </item>
        <item>
        </item>
   </notes>
</item>
```

notes is a child of the first item und the other items are childs of notes.
if i want to parse this i get the notes as normal items.

i thought it would be simple if i just rename the childs of notes to "noteitem"

is there a simple way to do this in Java?

thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: You might consider running an XSLT over the file first to translate the names as indicated prior to parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Why parse when you can use XSteam?
you can find nice and quick tutorial [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, if you really want to do what you stated, an XSLT us an option. Just define a style sheet transformation, apply it to the original input document and then parse the results of the transform as XML.

Here is a good starting point:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html

Comment: i have no clue about xslt, i think i first have to read somt tutorials about that. will try that

Comment: Added a link to get you going in the right direction if you choose this approach.

Comment: i have no clue how to handle this problem with xslt. may problem is that i have a String containing up to 50 item objects und each could have a high amount of notes, but it might be there are no notes at all. is it possible to do that by xslt? maybe i could get an example working for just one item where i know i have maybe 3 comments.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [Parsing XML files in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: i already have a DOM parser which works fine, aslong as i delet the notes bevor i parse it. the problem is that the items in the notes have the same strukture as the parent ones